# help with gloss reflections!

Tags: render-layers, reflection, emission, shader-nodes

I'm in dire need of some help here, as you can see in the second photo both, the car and the light that illuminate it, reflect on the ground plane I added.

I'd need to keep the car's reflection only avoiding the emitter's reflection thus having a cleaner look on the image.

From what I've heard software like Corona and V-Ray can just deactivate reflections per object but on Blender it just doesn't exist.

I'd be down with whatever gets me the result, be it layering or nodes, but I'd need a replicable solution that I could use in all my renders, share videos, forum pages, and anything related all help is and will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance - Calo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using cycles or eevee?

Comment: can you add a copy of your blend file minus the car to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  I think there's a solution but I'd rather test it against your actual light setup.

Comment: @MartyFouts: but then the object is much darker and i think callofugi doesn't want that

Comment: if you just want to have the light not shown in render i think you have to solve this with compositing and different view layers

Comment: i think that layers should be the way to do it cause i can't just torn off gloss, that is needed for the car's reflection